# Regex Syntax is invalid in Web.Configre rewrite

Tags: regex, web-config

Can anyone tell me why my regex isn't working here?

```
    <rule name="Redirect to http" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^(?i)\Q/\Ehome\Q/\E?private$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

when I add this script i get the an HTTP 500.22 error;

> The expression ^(?i)\Q/\Ehome\Q/\E?private$ has syntax which is not valid.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Please demonstrate with sample input and expected behavior.

Comment: Asaph as above i get the 500.22 error. syntax looks ok to me? i also tried without the ^ and $

Comment: You do not need the Q/E operators because the slash is not a special char. You also need no `(?i)` as you use ignorecase=true. Use `^/home/private$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `\Q`/`\E` operators because the slash is not a special regex metacharacter.

You also need no `(?i)` as you use `ignoreCase=true`.

Use `^/home/private$`.

Comment: yes thanks for that. out of interest does .net inject the case ignore?

Comment: I am not sure it is a .NET regex that is used here, it might be an ECMAScript regex. .NET regex supports inline options, or modifiers, so the `(?i)^/home/private$` is a valid .NET pattern.